# How to pass Dynamic choice parameter value to Shell in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Dynamic parameter plugin and checked the check box This build is parameterized and selected dynamic choice parameter and created a drop down using following script.

> `def list = ["app1","app2","app3"]`

Now I want to pass the value of the drop down to Shell

For example in shell I am executing the command

```
mkdir parameter
```

In place of parameter if I choose app1 from the dropdown it should replace parameter as below

```
mkdir app1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the Dynamic parameter plugin, but with built in Jenkins parameters the notation is the following:

```
mkdir ${list}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.

How many builds/Jobs we can run parallely at a time on jenkins and is there any link or document that helps me understand better abbout jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins Documentation http://www.wakaleo.com/download-jenkins-the-definitive-guide. Would you please ask your question seperately from this question?